# Removing the last 2 elements in an array - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have this array - `[49, 33, 8, 45, 20, 6, 34, 50, 31, 36, 28, 42, 35, 32, 7, 2, 9, 1, 18, 21]` how can I get this return - `[49, 33, 8, 45, 20, 6, 34, 50, 31, 36, 28, 42, 35, 32, 7, 2, 9, 1]` I've tried this and it doesn't work. `array.size - 2`..

Comment: `array[0...-2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`array = [49, 33, 8, 45, 20, 6, 34, 50, 31, 36, 28, 42, 35, 32, 7, 2, 9, 1, 18, 21]`

for removing last two elements use

`a[0..-3]`

or

`a[0..a.length-3]`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
array = array[0..-3]
```

This tells Ruby to take the slice of the array from index 0 (the first element) to index -3 (the third from last element), omitting the last two elements.

Alternately, you can also modify the array in place using [`Array#slice!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21):

```
array.slice!(-2, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `pop` method removes (and returns) the last element from an array. It takes an optional argument:

```
a = [49, 33, 8, 45, 20, 6, 34, 50, 31, 36, 28, 42, 35, 32, 7, 2, 9, 1, 18, 21] 

a.pop(2)

p a # => [49, 33, 8, 45, 20, 6, 34, 50, 31, 36, 28, 42, 35, 32, 7, 2, 9, 1]
```

Comment: this should be the answer